# running dr racket on asus chromebook without ubuntu

Tags: racket

I have asus chromebook c100p. i am in developer mode. I installed dr racket while in developer mode by entering crosh, then typing shell then finding the location of downloads and while in that location typing racket.sh (i renamed it to racket.sh) after that i went into the directory of racket and am trying to run drracket by typing ./drracket it says bash: ./drracket permission denied. i tried chmod +x drracket and chmod u+x drracket still it says permission denied. the rights of the file are -rwxr-xr-x

Comment: do `ls -al` on dr racket directory and note group and user permissions

Comment: Try prefixing the commands with `sudo` to run as a super-user.

Answer (score 0):

I know next to nothing about your operating system, but I do think that it might be helpful to know that the drracket 'binary' is actually just a shell script that invokes 'racket' with certain arguments. Take a look inside the drracket file.